# Haskell type inference results in error message pointing at the wrong variable

Tags: haskell

loading the following code in ghci

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall   #-}


--following gives a type error about the arg int not str
bug ::  String -> Int -> Int 
bug str int =  num 
  where num =  str * 10  +  int 

-- the following gives a type error about the arg str as expected 
works ::  String -> Int -> Int 
works str int = str * 10  +  int
```

that gives the following errors:

```
:reload
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( bugTI.hs, interpreted )

bugTI.hs:6:16: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Int’
      Expected: Int
        Actual: String
    • In the expression: num
      In an equation for ‘bug’:
          bug str int
            = num
            where
                num = str * 10 + int
  |
6 | bug str int =  num 
  |                ^^^

bugTI.hs:7:29: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected: String
        Actual: Int
    • In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘int’
      In the expression: str * 10 + int
      In an equation for ‘num’: num = str * 10 + int
  |
7 |   where num =  str * 10  +  int 
  |                             ^^^

bugTI.hs:10:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Int’
      Expected: Int
        Actual: String
    • In the first argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘str’
      In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘str * 10’
      In the expression: str * 10 + int
   |
10 | works str int = str * 10  +  int
   |                 ^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

The error for line 7 in the function bug says that it expects int to be a String which makes no sense as it is in an arithmetic expression.

The corresponding err for line 10 in the function works correctly says that it expects str to be an Int which makes sense.

It seems to me that the error for line 7 is at best misleading, at worst (and unlikely) a bug. Can somebody explain why the error points to the wrong variable? I assume there is something I don't understand.

Comment: The `(*)` is defined for *any* `Num` type, so you can strictly speaking make `String` a `Num` type, and thus define `(+)`, `(*)`, etc. on such type.

Comment: ...who knows, you might have wanted `String` as the result with `Num String` instance.

Comment: @Willen, thanks for all your help. It was a toss-up as to which answer was best. Abastro, as there is no Num String instance in the code I didn't think the compiler might think I wanted String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell does type inference in two "directions" at once.

1. **Bottom-up:** by looking at all the parts of an expression, what should be the type of the whole expression
2. **Top-down:** by looking at where this expression is used, what type should it have in order to fit into that context

If there is any place where the two do not agree, there will be a type error reported.

GHC's error messages call type it's worked out by "bottom-up" analysis the "actual type", and the type it's worked out by "top-down" analysis the "expected type". But don't be confused by this terminology; it's not that the "expected type" any more **correct** than the actual type. It is not telling you that the type **should** be the expected type but actually is the actual type. It's just telling you that two different lines of analysis lead to a contradiction about what the type of the expression is.

As such, it's kind of absurd to say that one of these error messages is "right" and the other is "wrong". They are **both** just telling you "these 2 things don't match, and they should". The compiler has no way of knowing which of the two types the expression "should" have if it was really correct; frequently *neither* of the two will work, no matter what else you change.

In particular, let's look at the type inference going on in the message you don't like:

```
bugTI.hs:7:29: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected: String
        Actual: Int
    • In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘int’
      In the expression: str * 10 + int
      In an equation for ‘num’: num = str * 10 + int
  |
7 |   where num =  str * 10  +  int 
  |                             ^^^
```

And for reference the code is:

```
bug ::  String -> Int -> Int 
bug str int =  num 
  where num =  str * 10  +  int
```

So to report a type error at the position indicated, we need to have **both** an "actual" (bottom-up) and "expected" (top-down) type for this occurence of `int`. The bottom-up type is easy; we know it's `Int` because the expression `int` only consists of a single variable reference, and that variable was declared to have type `Int`.

The expected type for `int` here depends on the context. `int` is occurring as the right operand to `+`, with the left operand being `str * 10`. `+` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a`. So to know what type we "expect" for `int` we need to know what type `str * 10` is inferred as.

`*` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a`, so `str` and `10` must have the same type, and the overall expression `str * 10` also has that type. `10` can be any type with a `Num` instance, but `str` already has a fixed type from the type signature; it is `String` (AKA `[Char]`).

Putting that all together, we now know that

1. the expressions `str`, `10`, `int`, `str * 10`, and `str * 10 + int`  all must have the same type
2. `str` has type `String`
3. `int` has type `Int`

These 3 facts cannot **all** be true. So we need to emit an error message.

This is the point where you go wrong. **You** have knowledge of your conceptual ideas about `Num` - that we do arithmetic on numbers and `String` isn't a number - so you say clearly we should "expect" `Int` for all of those, and the error that should be reported is that `str` has actual type `String` and expected type `Int`. But the compiler cannot possible know about your conceptual ideas about what `Num` is "for". Without that, your interpretation of the code is not any more valid than doing the opposite: saying that all of those expressions are expected to have type `str` and it's `int` that doesn't match! Exactly **because** there is no consistent typing here, there are multiple ways to get "as close as possible" and then report an error. It is essentially arbitrary which form the error takes in the error message<sup>1</sup>; neither is better than the other. So neither one can be the "wrong" error message.<sup>2</sup>

Without knowing the really fine details of the type checker implementation, I would hazard a *guess* based on this that it simply encountered the `str * 10` first and "committed" to `String` at that point; it knows enough even without looking ahead to know that choosing `String` as the type of both `10` and also of `str * 10` is the only possible chance it has of accepting this code, so there is "nothing to lose" by doing that. And then when it later also finds a requirement forcing that same type to also be `Int`, it reports an error.<sup>3</sup>

Now you noted in comments that there is **also** another error under this interpretation that `str`, `10`, and `int` are all expected to be `String`. That is the error that this choice will require an instance `Num String`, and there is no such instance visible to the compiler. It doesn't report that error because it is "behind" this one; the compiler needs to go looking for an `Num` instance that matches whatever type is chosen for `str`, `10`, and `int`, but it doesn't make sense to go looking for that instance until after we've figured out what instance we need! That requires pinning down the type involved, and having realised that there is **no** consistent type it's pointless even trying to resolve the `Num` constraint. This is an error **whether or not** `Num Int` or `Num String` or `Num <anything-else>` hold true.

---

<sup>1</sup> As evidence for my claim that which way around the error is reported is arbitrary, I don't even get the same error messages as you when I tried this. I don't know whether it's just a different version of GHC, or whether it would change sometimes even for the same version. But I get an error about `int` not being `String` for both `bug` and `works`:

```
foo.hs:6:16: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Int’
      Expected: Int
        Actual: String
    • In the expression: num
      In an equation for ‘bug’:
          bug str int
            = num
            where
                num = str * 10 + int
  |
6 | bug str int =  num
  |                ^^^

foo.hs:7:29: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected: String
        Actual: Int
    • In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘int’
      In the expression: str * 10 + int
      In an equation for ‘num’: num = str * 10 + int
  |
7 |   where num =  str * 10  +  int
  |                             ^^^

foo.hs:11:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Int’
      Expected: Int
        Actual: String
    • In the expression: str * 10 + int
      In an equation for ‘works’: works str int = str * 10 + int
   |
11 | works str int = str * 10  +  int
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

foo.hs:11:30: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected: String
        Actual: Int
    • In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘int’
      In the expression: str * 10 + int
      In an equation for ‘works’: works str int = str * 10 + int
   |
11 | works str int = str * 10  +  int
   |
```

---

<sup>2</sup> In fact these aren't even the only two possibilities. Absent wider context, it's just as likely that `int` and `str` are both "correct", and the bug is that the wrong **functions** were used on them (i.e. it's `+` and `*` that are wrong). GHC could quite reasonably report that this occurrence of `+` has expected type `String -> Int -> Int` and actual type `Int -> Int -> Int`, or something similar; that is *also* another equivalent way of reporting the same fundamental inconsistency that is present in your code.

I don't believe it will (often? ever?) actually report errors in that form. As far as I can recall it reports errors about arguments not fitting the function, rather than the function not fitting the arguments. I don't actually know why, whether it's a deliberate decision (for simpler error messages?) or just an accident of the type checker code works. But it's always a possibility for the real mistake that the programmer made, so you need to read errors with this sort of possible translation in mind.

---

<sup>3</sup> And I suppose that this doesn't happen in the `works` case because you don't have the intermediate `num` definition that can be inferred its own type; instead the `str * 10 + int` expression occurrs in a context where it is known that it should result in `Int`, because it is directly the return value of the `works` function that is declared to return `Int`. Although as I noted in my previous footnote, this doesn't happen when I run it. But that's fine. There is no one correct order in which GHC is required to consider the pieces of information available to it before it notices the inconsistency.

Comment: One critical thing that confused me is that there is no String instance of Num in the code but I guess the compiler has to assume there could be one in another file? I feel that the use of "Expected" and "Actual" in the error messages is confusing. I think I focused too much on one error message. I have to look at both error messages for function bug to see that there is an inconsistency.

Comment: @GeorgeCo That is a general principle of how instances work, yes. The compiler does not assume all the instances it can see now are all the instances that exist. So it's never going to look at two paths, see that one of them would require a `Num String` instance and so choose the other path. There has to be something *else* forcing the choice of path (if nothing forces either path you will get an ambiguity error). However that's not even relevant here; it can tell that all paths are wrong **before** it gets up to looking for instances, so the lack of `Num String` certainly won't influence it.

Comment: @GeorgeCo I agree with you that "Actual" and "Expected" is a little confusing (particularly "Expected"). But I can't come up with any better single words for the concepts "from its building blocks" and "from its context". You just have to learn what they mean as technical terms and remember that; the ordinary English meaning is only a vague hint towards the technical meaning. But that's true of just about every word that appears in compiler output, for any language (and a lot of words in any document talking about programming languages). It's just a fact of life of being a programmer.

Answer (score 5):

> It seems to me that the error for line 7 is at best misleading, at worst (and unlikely) a bug. Can somebody explain why the error points to the wrong variable? I assume there is something I don't understand.

There is nothing "special" about the [**`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42-), [**`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-), etc. functions. These are just functions defined in the `Num` typeclass.

You can make other types a member of the `Num` typeclass as well, this often happens if people define their own numerical-like types.

So you could, if you wanted to, define an instance for `Num` for a `String` type, or for a list in general. You could for example encode a number by the length of the list, and thus derive arithmetic on it. Then that would look like:

```
import Data.List(genericReplicate)

instance Num [a] where
    (+) = (++)
    
    (*) = (<*)
    
    abs = id
    
    signum = take 1
    
    fromInteger = (`genericReplicate` undefined)
    
    xs - ys = drop (length ys) xs
```

I agree that this does not make much sense as an instance for `Num`, but it is is one of the possible ways to implement this.

What Haskell is complaining about is that the two operands and the return type all need to have the same type. Indeed, in the signature `Num a => a -> a -> a`, the `a` is used for the two operands and the return type.

Since `int` has as type `Int` by the type signature, it means that the two operands of the addition needs to be `Int`s, and hence the result of `str * 10` should be an `Int`, that is not a problem for `10`, but a problem for `str`. Even if `Num [a]` would hold, it still means that this would error, since you can not multiply an `Int` with a `Double` for example, or add an `Integer` and `Int` together.

Comment: `(*) = (<*)` is a cute alternate definition here, I think?

Comment: `signum = take 1` is also nice.

Comment: The first and third error messages correctly state that str should be an Int. My question is about the second error message that says int should be a String, i.e. Haskell expected int to be a String. Why?

Comment: @GeorgeCo: as written at the end of the answer, the two operand types and the result type both need to have the same type...

Comment: I agree that they all have to be the same type, i.e. Int. The error message for the second function is correct as it expected str to be an Int but it is a String. But the first error messages for the second function incorrectly states int should be a String. As the code does not have a Num instance for String I don't understand the relevance of that part of your answer.

Comment: @GeorgeCo: the type checker never reaches the point where it validates the `instance Num`, since it already reached a point where it found out an inconsistency;

Comment: Let me rephrase, you seem to agree  with me, the problem is with str; it should be an Int. However Haskell, on line 7 says int should be a String. I don't understand why it expects int to be a String. It didn't says int should be a String in the first function which is semantically equivalent to the second function.

Comment: @GeorgeCo: no, in that case it should say something as "No instance `Num String`. The reason it here errors is because of the fact that the two operands and the return type should be the same, and since it has derived that the first operand is a `String`, it thus errors on the fact that the second operand is not.

Comment: The expression "str * 10  +  int" is the same in both functions. In the second function it derived the type of the expression to be Int. Why does it think the type of the same expression in the first function is String?

Comment: @GeorgeCo: because due to the `where` clause, the typechecker handles it in a different order.

Comment: The error on line 6 says it derived the type to be Int but the error on line 7 says the type is String. The type checker seems to be contradicting itself.

Comment: @GeorgeCo: no, it found out that `str` is a `String`, so `str * 10` is then a `String`, and `str * 10 + int` is thus a `String`, so that means `num` will be a `String`, and then it sees that the return type of your function should be an `Int`, so that is the second error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248043/discussion-between-george-co-and-willem-van-onsem).